# How to compare arrays based on the value contained on a certain index in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, indexing, string-comparison

I have two arrays, one with strings that are questions and the other one with it's answers which are also strings, the answer for the question which is in the first position of the array @questions is also in the first position but in the @answers, and it's the same for all the questions, so what i want to do is to ask the question to the user, and if he doesn't answer what was expected, he asked to try again.

This is my code so far:
but i'm getting the following error : file_mng.rb:72:in `block in play': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
def play

  arrange_arrays

  #The method arrange_arrays fills the arrays @questions and @answers in
  #a way that, the answer for the question in the first position of the
  #array @questions is located also in the first position of the array @answers, 
  #so the index matches for the arrays.

  puts

  @questions.each_with_index do |question, i|

    puts question
    puts
    puts "TYPE YOUR ANSWER"
    puts
    answer = gets.chomp

    while answer != @answers[i]
      puts
      puts "INCORRECT, TRY AGAIN"
    end
    puts
    puts "CORRECT !"
  end
  puts
  puts "QUESTIONS ARE OVER, CONGRATULATIONS!"
end

def arrange_arrays
        #everything located in a odd line is an question
        #everything lcoated in an even line is an answer

        File.open("questionary.out").each_line do |line|
            i = i+1

            if i % 2 == 0
                @answers << line.to_s.downcase.chomp
            else 
                @questions << line.to_s.downcase.chomp
            end
        end
    end
```

Thanks a million for reading this.

Answer (score 2):

The error is on this line:

```
while answer != @answers[i]
```

As the error message suggests, you're calling `[]` on `nil`, which means `@answers` is `nil`. You should look at your `arrange_arrays` method, as it doesn't seem to be setting `@answers`.

P.S. There's another problem on this line: You're using `while` where you should be using `if`. Once you fix the `@answers` problem, this will print "INCORRECT, TRY AGAIN" infinitely when the answer is incorrect.

Comment: That's so weird, because when i print both of the arrays from inside of the play method, it prints them with they actual values and not empty, i just added the arrange_arrays to my question, if you mind giving it a look :)

Comment: `arrange_arrays` is not going to work as written. You can't do `i = i + 1` if you haven't initialized `i`. The fact that it's not raising an error suggests to me that the `each_line` block is never being entered, although I can't account for that.

Comment: sorry i missed the i variable initialization (i=0) when copying the code to stack overflow, and i'm sure that the method works, because when i print the arrays, they are filled with the data from the file, that's the think that got me confused